# Hibernate criteria with referenced column returning infinite error

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, projection

I have a model for a table

```
@Entity(name="gpl_bd_stage")
public class GplBdStage implements Serializable {

/** Primary key. */
protected static final String PK = "stageId";

/**
 * The optimistic lock. Available via standard bean get/set operations.
 */
@Column(name="created_on")
private Timestamp createdOn;
@Column(nullable=false, length=250)
private String stage;
@Column(name="updated_on")
private Timestamp updatedOn;
@Column(name="record_display_order", precision=2)
private BigDecimal recordDisplayOrder;
@Column(name="escalation_1_timeline", precision=131089)
private BigDecimal escalation1Timeline;
@Column(name="escalation_2_timeline", precision=131089)
private BigDecimal escalation2Timeline;
@Column(name="escalation_3_timeline", precision=131089)
private BigDecimal escalation3Timeline;
@Id @Column(name="stage_id", unique=true, nullable=false, precision=10)
private int stageId;
@Column(name="tat_days", precision=131089)
private BigDecimal tatDays;
@Column(name="is_active", length=1)
private boolean isActive;
@OneToMany(mappedBy="gplBdStage")
private Set<GplBdBusinessDeal> gplBdBusinessDeal;
@OneToMany(mappedBy="gplBdStage")
private Set<GplBdDealEscalation> gplBdDealEscalation;
@OneToMany(mappedBy="gplBdStage")
private Set<GplBdEscalationRule> gplBdEscalationRule;
@ManyToOne @JoinColumn(name="created_by")
private GplBdUser gplBdUser;

@OneToMany(mappedBy="gplBdStage3")

private Set<GplBdStage> gplBdStage4;

@ManyToOne @JoinColumn(name="parent_stage")
private GplBdStage gplBdStage3;
@ManyToOne @JoinColumn(name="updated_by")
private GplBdUser gplBdUser2;
@OneToMany(mappedBy="gplBdStage")
private Set<GplBdTag> gplBdTag;
```

When I try to use the below query for fetching specific columns from a table :

```
Criteria cr = session.createCriteria(GplBdStage.class,"e")
        .setProjection(Projections.projectionList()
        .add(Projections.property("gplBdStage3"),"gplBdStage3")
        .add(Projections.property("stageId"),"stageId")
        .add(Projections.property("stage"),"stage"))
        .setResultTransformer(Transformers.ALIAS_TO_ENTITY_MAP);
        List<GplBdStage> result = cr.list();
```

It gives infinite recursion with infinite result

Where I want something like this

```
[{"stage":"First Contract","gplBdStage3":{"stage":"First Contract","stageId":1},"stageId":1}]
```

I use spring boot hibernate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are getting infinite json loop as you have `@OneToMany` and `@ManyToOne` associations.

Try to restrict it by using `@JsonManagedReference` and `@JsonBackReference` annotations

For Jackson to work well, one of the two sides of the relationship should not be serialized, in order to avoid the infite loop that causes your stackoverflow error.

```
    // This is pseudo code
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "--" cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JsonManagedReference
    private Set<?> -- = ;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "--", nullable = false)
    @JsonBackReference
    private -- --;
```

Or

If not interested in getting some entity data just use `@JsonIgnore` in any one of the class

Comment: But now I am not able to access the coulmn from finall in repo

Comment: What is finall and repo ?

Comment: Did you use `@JsonIgnore` ?